# How to exclude files from being processed by tsc?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

How do you stop `tsc` from processing a Javascript file required by another?

I want to run full checks on my main `index.js`, but it `requires()` a `generated.js` Javascript file created by `emcc`, which is perfectly fine, but doesn't pass a lot of `tsc`'s checks.

I tried adding the file to my exclude list in my `tsconfig.json`, like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
        "dom",
        "webworker"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "index.js"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "generated.js"
  ]
}
```

but that had no effect. When I run `tsc --build tsconfig.json` I get a tone of errors from `generated.js`.

Comment: If you can somehow get `// @ts-nocheck` on top of `generated.js` when it's compiled I think that's the simplest thing to do

Comment: @apokryfos You're right. That worked.

Answer (score 1):

The `tsconfig.json` file looks for typescript files by default, while you are providing it `.js` files. you can change the file extensions from `.js` to `.ts` to let typescript look after them. so your `tsconfig.json` file may end up looking like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "lib": [
        "dom",
        "webworker"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "index.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "generated.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: But my files aren't Typescript. They're Javascript. I use other tools like browserfy to bundle everything for deployment, which doesn't accept Typescript.

Comment: @Cerin If your `index.js` is not a generated file, you can set `"checkJs: false"` in `tsconfig.json` & separate the typescript part of your project to another directory with `index.ts` & let typescript compile that to the equivalent `index.js` in your desired directory (that becomes typescript's `dist` folder) from which browserify reads for bundling.